# Sign java applet without security pop-up

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate, jar-signing

I have question about signing java applets. I have self-signed applet. When i open webpage i have security warning dialog, and i have to confirm permissions. Is it possible (for example via SSL certificate or i don't know, some code certificate) that this dialog will not appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible ... that this dialog will not appear?

Only if there is a security bug in the JRE.

If the code is digitally signed using a verified certificate, the security warning will be more mild, the signer identified in the dialog, and `Always Trust` might be checked by default.

Answer (score 7):

Get a certificate from a trusted authority, like [Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/) or [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com). This way you'll ensure your users, that you are a trusted party (so they might more willingly click the `Always trust content from this publisher` checkbox).

You - as an application developer - cannot disable this dialog completely, but your users can.
Look at the [`Avoiding security` chapter of this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html#gcexdl) to find out how.

Comment: *"your users will be asked to allow the applet to run."*  Your users will be prompted even if the code is signed with a cert. from a trusted authority.  It is for their protection.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of that!. I did some digging, and found a reference on oracle's site and edited the answer. Thanks!